# How to set style of an element while using setInterval?

Tags: javascript, html

I want make effect for my button. When I clicked, I want increase left attribute of button. And alter auto return left=0px

```
elm.style.left = "0px";
```

https://codepen.io/hunh-vn-thin/pen/jOEEPNz

Comment: why can't you do that? is there an error in the console? does nothing happen at all? please clarify

Comment: I see the problem ... newLeft is `undefined` ... `undefined + 10` is `NaN` - initialise newLeft with a **Number**

Comment: I fixed it, but button cannot return left=0px in fade function

Comment: I did not understand that, please find a way and fix it for me

Comment: `var newLeft = 0` - now it's a **Number** -

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the line:

```
fade(element);
```

with `setTimeout` function:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    newleft = 0;

    fade(element);
}, 50);
```

In this case, it means: waiting until the animation is done.

It also because when you run `setInterval` function, all of the code inside the function will be called imediately. So, if you want to wait 50 miliseconds, you can wrap it with `setTimeout`.

If you want to repeat the animation for the next click, you can set `newleft = 0` inside the `setTimeout` function.

Comment: *when you run setInterval function, all of the code inside the function will be called imediately* no, that's completely and utterly wrong - the**only** issue was the initial value for `newLeft` - everything else in this answer is complete misinformation